# IOS Auto layout issue for IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I am new to IOS.

I am working with auto layout. Everything works fine for IOS 8. But view's frame is not extended to edge in IOS 7,

I have attached screen shot of both.

In IOS 7 a strange white line on the header you can see.(You can see battery is cut off.)

Thanks for help.

[image: IOS 7 screen shot]

[image: IOS 8 screen shot]

Comment: Please tell us your autolayout constraints. Did you add them in interface builder or in your code?

Comment: Set proper  autolayout constraints and remove constraints if you have any in this view.

Comment: try to uncheck "Constrain to margins"

Comment: So… any update from you?